# Почему модуль requests не использует proxy?

Tags: python, requests, proxy

Задача каждый раз с изменённым IP опрашивать сайт, но requests в упор не хочет использовать прокси.

```
def get_ip(i):
    with open("asd.json", "r") as read_file:
        data = json.load(read_file)

    x = data[i]

    return x["ip"] + ":" + x["port"]

x = 1
while 1:
    x = x + 1

    proxies = {
       'http': str(get_ip(x))
    }

    print(proxies)
    session = requests.Session()
    session.proxies.update(proxies)

    session.get("http://irisnet.ru")
    time.sleep(random.randrange(1, 5))

    session.close()
    print("Cycled")
```

С таким кодом в логах сервера указаны запросы с моего компьютера, а не со стороны прокси.

Comment: Покажите пример значения, которое возвращает get_ip

Comment: проверьте работоспособность прокси. Проверьте работает ли без сессии. Тот ли тип прокси указали. Выглядит так , что должно работать

Comment: @andreymal пример 10.0.0.4:3128

Comment: @inzem77 прокси работоспособные. Через браузер работают если вводить вручную

Comment: Протокол забыли указать

Comment: Так 10.0.0.4 это же private адрес, который находится (скорее всего) с Вами в одной сети и за одним NAT'ом. Поэтому, возможно, в логах сервера и пишет, что запросы с одного и того же адреса (внешнего адреса NAT'а).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Хотя в [документации](https://2.python-requests.org/en/latest/api/#module-requests) и написано, что:

> proxies = None
> Dictionary mapping protocol or protocol and host to the URL of the proxy (e.g. {‘http’: ‘foo.bar:3128’, ‘http://host.name’: ‘foo.bar:4012’}) to be used on each Request.

но у меня иначе как:

```
proxy = f'{url}:{port}'  # url без протокола
session.proxies = {
    'http': 'http://' + proxy,
    'https': 'https://' + proxy
}
```

не работает... Попробуйте так же?
Или у себя сделайте:

```
return "http://" + x["ip"] + ":" + x["port"]
```